# How to build a Maven Android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am testing the code here : https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java. Under features there is this sweet sounding line : "Android is fully supported". But being completely new to maven I can make neither head nor tail of the instructions. How do I build a basic Android test project with this code? Simply adding the source code from the repo to my project is showing lot of errors. If there is a command line way of doing this that would be fine too.

Comment: An answer removed for plagiarism suggested https://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/

Answer (score 1):

Steps to build a Maven Android project in eclipse

1. Install m2e(mavel plugin) to your ecplise.
2. Right click Create Maven project
3. Click next and in Catalog select Android
4. Give group id `com.example` and Artifact id `Project name`
5. click finish.

Comment: or File-->New-->Maven Project

Comment: Under file->new-project->maven project I don't see any catalog option

Answer (score 0):

Typically you do this by importing an "Existing Maven Project". You get this option in the Import dialog when you have installed m2e. For Android you will additionally need the Android Connector before doing the import. Here it gets nasty. You can install the connector from `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Maven` -> `Discovery` -> `Open Catalog`.

To be honest I had no luck with this connector yet. So the second option is (you don't even need m2e here):

- Install [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
- Open the command line and navigate to your downloaded sources where the `pom.xml` is located
- run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create eclipse project files
- Import it as "Existing Project into Workspace" in the import dialog.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions as they appeared to be simplest. I could get past mvn eclipse:eclipse. Got a message: BUILD SUCCESS. But while importing into eclipse I get this: "No marketplace entries found to handle Execution npm-install, in /pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."  As always there is hardly any useful information in help. Stuck here..

Comment: Well I didn't expect that if you import the project as "Existing Project" and not as "Existing Maven Project". But you should be able to ignore that message anyway and import it. Then you can remove the Maven nature by right clicking the project -> `Maven` -> `Disable Maven Nature`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I imported as "existing maven project" instead of "existing project". OK , I finally got the project into eclipse. But the original question still remains.. how do I create an Android application project using classes from this project. Sorry for being completely lost here ..

Comment: I have asked a related question here with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174038/how-to-build-android-test-code-for-socket-io-client-java

Answer (score 0):

1. install m2e plug-in your eclipse.
2. install android m2e plug-in.
3. create new maven project.
4. select archtype:android-quickstart by typing android in filter.
5. finish you will get maven android project.
   and add this plugin in pom

   org.eclipse.m2e
                   lifecycle-mapping
                   1.0.0
                   
                       
                           
                               
                                   
                                       
                                           com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2
                                       
                                       
                                           android-maven-plugin
                                       
                                       
                                           [3.8.2,)
                                       
                                       
                                           consume-aar
6. finally update the project by rightclicking on project->maven->update project.