# How to build Android test code for socket.io-client.java

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, socket.io

This question is related to [How to build a Maven Android project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134761/how-to-build-a-maven-android-project-in-eclipse). Using suggestions from @user714965 I was able to build the code in project : https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java. Now I am trying to compile an Android test project. I created a new Android project and under Java Build Path specified the socket.io-client project as dependency. But I am getting compilation errors. Eclipse is unable to find Emitter Class.
This is the relevant code:

```
public class SocketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Socket mSocket = null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to server");
            mSocket = IO.socket("<my tested socket.io server address>");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
            }

        }).on("event", new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Event");
            }

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect");
            }

        });

        mSocket.connect();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: does the socket must be in a *AsyncTask* ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like dependent libraries are not resolved. Did you install all of them correctly?

- engine.io-client 0.3.0
- Java-WebSocket 1.3.0
- org.json 20090211 (installed in Android as default)

`Emitter` is included in engine.io-client.

Comment: I see that engine.io-client 0.3.0 and Java-WebSocket 1.3.0 are present as "Referenced Libraries" in the socket.io-client project. I have listed socket.io-client project as a dependency. Is that not enough? Or Should I copy those libraries directly into my project? Probably I am missing something basic here ..

Comment: @everydayapps Sorry, I'm not familiar with Eclipse (An IntelliJ IDEA user).

Comment: No problem. I could try IntelliJ just to test this code. Have you successfully built and tested on Android using IntelliJ?

Comment: Not actually, I will create a demo app.

Comment: @nkzawa hi, did you create the demo app ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot respond to the comments (new StackOverflow user) but I have gotten the library to work in Android Studio via build.gradle. If you are primarly developing for Android they suggest moving to Android Studio as it will soon be the [supported IDE](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

**EDIT**

I can connect to a socketIO server built on nodejs from an android application with this library from nkzawa. Reference to [repository](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java).

Add library as gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
```

I wrote a class to hold my socket:

```
public class SocketIO{

  Socket sock = null;

  public SocketIO(){
    try{
       sock = IO.socket('<connection string>');

       //Place all events here as per documention
       sock.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener(){
         @Override
         public void call(Object... args){
           System.out.println("connect");
         }
       });

    sock.connect();
    } catch(URISyntaxException e){
      e.printStatckTrace();
    }
  };

  //Helper function for emiting from android
  public void sEmit(String event, JSONObject obj){
    if(socket.connected()){
      sock.emit(event, obj);
    }
  }
}
```

And use it in my activity:

```
SocketIO socket = new SocketIO();
```

I had some initial trouble getting the library to work but it has been flawless since, the "issues" section of the github repository is very helpful.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you post detailed instructions for us Studio newbies? I have never managed to get anything to work in Studio.

Comment: I am using Android Studio Beta 0.8.14. I'm not sure where to begin getting Android Studio to work, my projects have both worked with a few tweaks after the import (File -> Import Project). To get this library to work you open thee build.gradle file in the app folder and add this line: compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0' under dependencies. The studio will compiles the code and make it usable in your project.

Comment: OK. I will give it a try. Just confirming - were you able to connect and exchange messages with Socket.io server ?