# Maven fails to build Android project (not using Eclipse)

Tags: android, xml, maven, dependencies

When I try build a current Android project with Maven (mvn package), I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project gs-maven-tabs: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/kleber/workspace/basic_tab/src/main/java/org/hello/HelloActivity.java:[5,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FragmentTabHost
[ERROR] location: package android.support.v4.app
[ERROR] /home/kleber/workspace/basic_tab/src/main/java/org/hello/HelloActivity.java:[9,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FragmentTabHost
[ERROR] location: class HelloActivity
[ERROR] /home/kleber/workspace/basic_tab/src/main/java/org/hello/HelloActivity.java:[16,20] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

related to this class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class HelloActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // Fragment TabHost as mTabHost
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello_layout);

        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"), Tab1Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"), Tab2Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"), Tab3Fragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

this error happens even I add this to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r6</version>
    </dependency>
```

What  I missing here?

ps.: my full pom.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-maven-tabs</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <android.sdk.path>/home/kleber/android-sdk-linux/</android.sdk.path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <executable>/home/kleber/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build a Maven Android project in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134761/how-to-build-a-maven-android-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: I am not using Eclipse to build the project (just Atom editor and command-line maven commands).

Comment: I'm not sure how you build your project while you code but it seems that the support library r6 does not have the FragmentTabHost try to change it to the latest lib available.

Comment: yes, it does have thid class. If I try build the project without maven (using eclipse/adt), i don't get this error. With maven and the pom.xml above, I can't build the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a [quick check in the jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/support-v4/r6), FragmentTabHost class is not in that library!

That is the main problem with maintaining two builds, IDE and CLI, after a few updates most of the time they are not the same.

You can find the most updated jars in the sdk extras... if they are not there download them via the SDK manager.

```
${SDK_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.0/support-v4-21.0.0.aar
```

Extract it and take the classes.jar (or convert it to apklib) from it and replace it with your **r6**repository file, or install it as a new jar:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=com.google.android \
-DartifactId=support-v4 -Dversion=21.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar



<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't have two builds (only one, built via CLI). I create a test project using eclipse/adt only to check if this missing class are available (answer: yes, they are).

Comment: also check the link I've provided the class is not in that jar that is the reason it fails

Comment: in the error, both FragmentActivity and FragmentTabHost are missing, but both are provided by the android support library, since when I use eclipse/adt I can use them.

Comment: You don't hear me... It doesn't matter that Eclipse can resolve it, it just means you don't use the same jar! Maven brings the jar in the link I've sent you and **that jar does not have the FragmentTabHost class**! That is the reason your build fails. Also r7 does not contain it.

Comment: and you know where I can find a jar that contains that class? that is the answer I am searching for.