# Why maven creates strange android-project-structure

Tags: java, android, maven

Using [How to build a Maven Android project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134761/) to create a maven project creates two modules who are 90% same.

This is part of the parent pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- the standard profile runs the instrumentation tests -->
        <id>standard</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>zopp.server</module>
            <module>zopp.server-it</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- the release profile does sign, proguard, zipalign ... but does not 
            run instrumentation tests -->
        <id>release</id>
        <!-- via this activation the profile is automatically used when the release 
            is done with the maven release plugin -->
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>zopp.server</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<modules>
    <module>zopp.server</module>
    <module>zopp.server-it</module>
</modules>
```

Why must that be executed to a different module?

The project Zopp has 2 android-apps and one api-library. This is the building result:

```
[INFO] android.zopp ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.107 s]
[INFO] zopp.server - Parent ............................... SUCCESS [  0.006 s]
[INFO] zopp.server - Application .......................... SUCCESS [  2.122 s]
[INFO] zopp.server-it - Integration tests ................. SUCCESS [ 15.914 s]
[INFO] zopp.client - Parent ............................... SUCCESS [  0.006 s]
[INFO] zopp.client - Application .......................... SUCCESS [  0.580 s]
[INFO] zopp.client-it - Integration tests ................. SUCCESS [ 15.916 s]
[INFO] zopp.api ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.506 s]
```

How to beat it down to only one project per app?

### Edit: Add complete poms between root and all server parts.

The server-pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>de.e-nexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>zopp.server-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>zopp.server</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>zopp.server - Application</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${parent.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>zopp.api</artifactId>
            <version>${parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- use the copy resources instead of resources, which adds it to 
                            the eclipse buildpath -->
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/templates/res</directory>
                                    <targetPath>${project.basedir}/res</targetPath>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <manifest>
                        <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                    </manifest>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>alignApk</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <!-- via this activation the profile is automatically used when the release 
                is done with the maven release plugin -->
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>signing</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <inherited>true</inherited>
                                <configuration>
                                    <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                                    <archiveDirectory />
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <keystore>${sign.keystore}</keystore>
                                    <alias>${sign.alias}</alias>
                                    <storepass>${sign.storepass}</storepass>
                                    <keypass>${sign.keypass}</keypass>
                                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-sigalg</argument>
                                        <argument>MD5withRSA</argument>
                                        <argument>-digestalg</argument>
                                        <argument>SHA1</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- the signed apk then needs to be zipaligned and we activate proguard 
                        and we run the manifest update -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <release>true</release>
                            <sign>
                                <debug>false</debug>
                            </sign>
                            <zipalign>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</inputApk>
                                <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk
                                </outputApk>
                            </zipalign>
                            <manifest>
                                <debuggable>false</debuggable>
                                <versionCodeAutoIncrement>true</versionCodeAutoIncrement>
                            </manifest>
                            <!-- Change to true to skip Proguard -->
                            <proguard>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <config>proguard.conf</config>
                            </proguard>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>alignApk</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>zipalign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk</file>
                                    <type>apk</type>
                                    <classifier>signed-aligned</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${project.build.directory}/proguard/mapping.txt</file>
                                    <type>map</type>
                                    <classifier>release</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-signed-aligned</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The server-it pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>de.e-nexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>zopp.server-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>zopp.server-it</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>zopp.server-it - Integration tests</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.e-nexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>zopp.server</artifactId>
            <type>apk</type>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.e-nexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>zopp.server</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <test>
                        <!--<skip>true|false|auto</skip> -->
                        <!--<instrumentationPackage>packageName</instrumentationPackage> -->
                        `
                        <!--<instrumentationRunner>className</instrumentationRunner> -->
                        <!--<debug>true|false</debug> -->
                        <!--<coverage>true|false</coverage> -->
                        <!--<logonly>true|false</logonly> avd -->
                        <!--<testsize>small|medium|large</testsize> -->
                        <createReport>true</createReport>
                        <!--<classes> -->
                        <!--<class>your.package.name.YourTestClass</class> -->
                        <!--</classes> -->
                        <!--<packages> -->
                        <!--<package>your.package.name</package> -->
                        <!--</packages> -->
                    </test>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>10</platform>
                    </sdk>
                                    </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The server-parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>android.zopp</artifactId>
        <groupId>de.e-nexus</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>zopp.server-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>zopp.server - Parent</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <version>${platform.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
                <version>${platform.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>10</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <zipalign>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </zipalign>
                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- the standard profile runs the instrumentation tests -->
            <id>standard</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>zopp.server</module>
                <module>zopp.server-it</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- the release profile does sign, proguard, zipalign ... but does not 
                run instrumentation tests -->
            <id>release</id>
            <!-- via this activation the profile is automatically used when the release 
                is done with the maven release plugin -->
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>zopp.server</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <modules>
        <module>zopp.server</module>
        <module>zopp.server-it</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

The root pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.e-nexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>android.zopp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version>2.3.3</platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.8.2</android.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>zopp.server</module>
        <module>zopp.client</module>
        <module>zopp.api</module>
    </modules>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Any reason not to use Android Studio and/or Gradle?

Comment: And the reason you have two modules is for actual code and tests. You probably won't want the tests to be bundled into the final application

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is Android Zopp a project of yours or are you trying to understand / build an existing opensource project? I just followed the steps in the most upvoted answer on the linked question and I don't have 2 modules created.

Comment: @Tunaki Zopp is a project of mine. Well, i have a parent who has 2 modules. You created the application, what type is the app?

Comment: @cricket_007 Codetests have their very own place in the project in maven (`src/test` right beside `src/main`), so why the split into modules? The final Application never contains tests, what makes you think they are bundled in the application?

Comment: There's different types of tests. The two modules clearly say client and server integration tests

Comment: @cricket_007 No the two modules are `server` and `server-it` for the server-part and `client` and `client-it` for the client part. So why the split into `server` and `server-it`?

Comment: Testing and implementation?

Comment: It is one application, why shall i have different versions for implementation and testing. I can have different versions for api and impl but for testing and impl? This is Weird. The imagination of bundle tests in a final application is weird also. Please explain it to me, i am confused of what you write.

Comment: I don't have an answer more than an opinion. Which is you don't want to clutter your main app code with tests. You're welcome to restructure the source directories to what makes sense to you

Comment: Why do you think to use `src/test` and `src/it` like maven pretent is a clutter? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: can you add the pom of the server module and the pom of the server-it module? (not the dependances nor the plugin, I want to see the parent part.)

Comment: @sab Added complete poms